# bootstrap container always on top

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have the following code:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 fixedContainer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Smith Service</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" ng-controller="ServiceStatus as serviceStatus">

            <!--Iterates over the services-->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6" ng-repeat="service in serviceStatus.services">
                <server-status name="service.name" status="service.status" nodes="service.nodes"></server-status>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<ng-view></ng-view>
```

I want to fix the div that has the fixedContainer class always on top. Inside ng-view there is a table, with scrollable data.

I define fixedContainer class as:

```
.fixedContainer {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1030;
top: 0;
```

}

but ng-view stay below the container, something is missing.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a JSfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: If i understand. Add padding-top to the body same as the height of the fixedContainer.

Comment: make sure you don't have padding/margin on the ng-view div or on the body (best to use reset.css)